# The subset consisting of $f\in C(D^2)$ which are constant on the boundary circle $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Let $C(D^2)$ be the algebra of real-valued continuous functions on the unit disk $D^2$ and let $A$ be the subset consisting of those $f\in C(D^2)$ with the property that they are constant on the boundary circle $S^1$.

1. Is $A$ a sub-algebra of $C(D^2)$?
2. Is $A$ dense in $C(D^2)$?
3. show that the spectrum of $A$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

For 1., I thought $A$ is indeed a sub-algebra. It has a unit element, just the scalar $\lambda=1$ and if $f_1, f_2$ both are constant on $S^1$, then $f_1\cdot f_2$ is still constant on $S^1$.

For 2., I know I have to prove that $A$ is point seperating, then it will be dense. I thought $A$ is not, but I'm not sure how to show this.

For 3., I have absolutely no clue why this is true. Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: For 3, it might help if you find an isomorphism between $A$ and $C(S^2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought about it but I have no idea.. Could you help me?

Comment: (Using notation regarding $D$ as a subset of $\Bbb C$ as opposed to $\Bbb R^2$:) If $f\in A$ what is $f(1)-f(-1)$? And if you take $D^2$ and identify $S^1$ to a single point, what topological space results?

Comment: $f(1)-f(-1)=c-c=0$ and if I take $D^2$ and identify $S^1$ to a single point, I'll get $S^2$. I think this is helpful, but I'm not sure what the next step would be

Comment: So you have the continuous map $\pi\colon D^2 \to S^2$. If you look at the pullback from $C(S^2)$ to $C(D^2)$ via $\pi$, what is the image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. could you clarify it?

Comment: If $X,Y$ are topological spaces, and $\varphi \colon X \to Y$ is a continuous map, we have the pullback $\varphi^{\ast} \colon C(Y) \to C(X)$ defined by $\varphi^{\ast}(f) = f\circ \varphi$. This pullback is always an algebra homomorphism, so the image is always a subalgebra of $C(X)$. In your case, check that $\pi^{\ast}$ is injective (it's an isometry), and that its image is $A$.